# Obtaining the Windows 7 CD key from its installation files

Tags: windows-7, product-key

Are there any files probably contained in the Windows directory that have the product key?

I need to re install the OS of my laptop but have misplaced the CD key.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [ProduKey](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html) to retrieve your key.

> ProduKey is a small utility that displays the ProductID and the CD-Key of Microsoft Office (Microsoft Office 2003, Microsoft Office 2007), Windows (Including Windows 7 and Windows Vista), Exchange Server, and SQL Server installed on your computer.
>
> This utility can be useful if you **lost the product key** of your Windows/Office, and you want to **reinstall it on your computer**.

[image]

Comment: ProduKey's official page is http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html

Answer (score 2):

I found this:

http://www.aboutonlinetips.com/how-to-recover-windows-7-vista-xp-product-keys/

> ### 21 Best Tools to Recover Windows 7/Vista/XP Product Keys
>
> A CD key (aka product key, activation key, key code, installation key,
>   and serial number) is used to identify that the copy of the program or
>   game is original. In simple terms, Product key is a long series of
>   numbers and letters that many software programs prompts you to enter
>   during the setup process. Windows does not provide a way to view the
>   product key of the application currently installed. If you have lost
>   your key or the printed registration card then you are out of luck.
>   Re-installing Windows requires you to have the original product key.
>   Following are the list of 21 Free Product Keys recovery tools that
>   scan through the Windows Registry to retrieve the Windows product keys
>   and all the serial numbers for the applications installed. The serial
>   keys finder tools listed below can be useful to recover your License
>   Key, CD Product key for Windows or Office programs while reinstalling
>   / repairing your Windows or Office setup.
>
> [image]
>
> 1) **[Magical Jelly Bean Keyfinder](http://magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/)**
>
> Windows 7/Vista/XP and Office 2007 Product Key (CD Key) can be recovered easily with the Magical Jelly
>   Bean Keyfinder. It is a powerful and freeware open source utility that
>   retrieves your Product Key used to install Windows from your registry.
>   It can even retrieve product keys from unbootable Windows
>   installations. The tool lets you print or save your License keys for
>   safe backup. Keyfinder also works with Windows 95, 98, ME, 2000,
>   Server 2003, Server 2008, Office XP, Office 2003 and its
>   community-updated configuration file helps in retrieving product keys
>   for many other applications too.
>
> 2) **[ProduKey](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html)**
>
> The tool helps in retrieving the ProductID and the CD-Key
>   of Microsoft Office (Microsoft Office 2003, Microsoft Office 2007),
>   Windows (Including Windows 7 and Windows Vista), Exchange Server, and
>   SQL Server installed on your computer. Using command-line options
>   ProductID can be grabbed for current operating system or for another
>   operating system/computer. For more information on ProduKey visit
>   nirsoft.
>
> 3) **[WinGuggle](http://www.aboutonlinetips.com/windows-7-product-key-recovery/)**
>
> It is a powerful tool that allows you to recover Windows
>   7/Vista/XP and Office Product Key (CD Key) quickly. In addition, you
>   can Set, Change, remove and Backup your Original Equipment
>   Manufacturer’s (OEM) Logo Information Settings.
>
> 4) **[WinKeyFinder](http://www.winkeyfinder.com/winkeyfinder-news/win-keyfinder-1.73-rc2.php)**
>
> WinkeyFinder 1.73RC2 allows you to recover lost
>   product keys, CD Keys or License keys your Windows XP, Windows Vista,
>   MS Office 2007, Windows me, 98, 2003 and .NET Product keys from the
>   registry and display it for you. The Product Key recovery tool helps
>   you to take back up of WinXP Activation Key, re-store WinXP activation
>   key, Change / copy Volume Serial number and save the product key By
>   Encrypting It. With WinkeyFinder 1.73RC2 unique passwords can be
>   generated by entering a combination of KeyCode.
>
> 5) **[Simple KeyFinder](http://www.winkeyfinder.com/winkeyfinder-news/simple-keyfinder.php)**
>
> Quickly recover your lost Windows Vista (32bit),
>   Windows xp, Windows 2000, Windows 2003 Product Key From Windows
>   Command Prompt. The tools helps you to retrieve CD Keys from existing
>   installations of Windows.
>
> 6) **[Windows Vista Cd Key Finder](http://www.winkeyfinder.com/winkeyfinder-news/windows-vista-cd-key-finder.php)**
>
> Recovers your windows Vista Cd Key or
>   product key safely and securely. Windows Vista Cd Key Finder allows
>   you to encrypt or decrypt the product key. Save CD Key, Copy to
>   Clipboard and print. The product key finder tool supports All versions
>   of Windows Vista.
>
> 7) **[Product Key Finder](http://davehope.co.uk/Projects/CPP-ProductKeyFinder.exe)**
>
> Product Key Finder retrieves license key
>   information (CD Keys) from the Windows registry and also helps in
>   recovering product keys of 200+ windows applications such Microsoft
>   Windows, Microsoft Office and Adobe Acrobat.
>
> 8) **[Keyfinder-Thing](http://download.cnet.com/Keyfinder-Thing/3000-2094_4-10491989.html)**
>
> The tool retrieves Serial numbers or CD Keys of
>   Microsoft software installed on your system. This free product key
>   recovery tool scans the system registry for 90 supported software
>   titles and displays product names and icons in the result window.
>   Keyfinder-Thing allows you to copy or export all keys to a text or
>   HTML file.
>
> 9) **[Product Key Finder PRO](http://www.gearboxcomputers.com/products/product-key-finder/)**
>
> A software utility allows you to recover
>   your License Key, CD Product key for Windows or Office programs while
>   reinstalling / repairing your Windows or Office setup. Recover your
>   lost key for (Windows) 2000, XP, 2003, Vista. (Office) XP, 2003, 2007.
>   The utility provides you with an option to save your product keys to a
>   file and Print your product keys for secure backup.
>
> 10) **[RockXP](http://www.download3k.com/DownloadLink1-RockXP.html)**
>
> It is a small but powerful tool that lets you recover all
>   Microsoft Software Serials instantly. With RockXP you can change your
>   XP key, save you XP activation key, retrieve your internet connection
>   parameters (like passwords), retrieve MSN login and password, recover
>   XP login and HASH password, display system password (LSA) and generate
>   random password. RockXP 4.0
>
> 11) **[Windows Product Key Finder Professional](http://shareme.com/download/windows-product-key-finder.html)**
>
> It is one of the best and
>   powerful Windows, Office, and Product Key Code Finder Retriever.
>   Product Key Finder PRO utility allows you to recover your CD Product
>   key for Windows. Recover your lost key or serial for (Windows) 2000,
>   XP, 2003, Vista. (Office) XP, 2003, 2007. Retrieve Product Keys for:
>   Windows 2000 Windows XP Windows 2003 Windows Vista Office XP Office
>   2003 Office 2007
>
> 12) **Product Key Finder**
>
> With the Product Key Finder you can easily
>   recover lost product key (CD Key) for Windows 7, Vista, 2008, XP,
>   2003, 2000, Microsoft Office, SQL Server, Exchange Server and many
>   other products.
>
> 13) **[License Crawler](http://www.klinzmann.name/files/licensecrawler.zip)**
>
> This free windows license key and product key
>   scanning utility scans your Windows Registry to retrieve the Windows
>   product keys and all the serial numbers for the applications
>   installed. This scanning tool finds Keys for Operating Systems:
>   Microsoft Windows 7, Windows Vista, Windows XP, Windows Server 2003,
>   Windows 2000, and Windows XP, Microsoft Office 2007, Office 2003, most
>   Adobe products, and many more.
>
> You can run License Crawler from a USB stick or via local network to
>   scan the computers. Once the search is completed users can get the
>   license keys or serial numbers from the screen directly in a detailed
>   list format.
>
> 14) **[Product Key Finder (OTT Solution)](http://www.ottsolutions.com/products/ProductKeyFinder/ProductKeyFinderV1.0.zip)**
>
> Product Key Finder is a free
>   tool that will display the installed Windows Product Key for Windows
>   operating systems (2000, 2003, XP, Vista, 2008, 7), 32-bit and 64-bit.
>   The tool also lets you save all product keys to a text or an xml file.
>   You can also change your Windows product key instantly without having
>   to re-install; this is helpful if you are using a leaked product key
>   and are unable to install updates.
>
> 15) **[geProduct Key Finder](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/gepkeyfinder.html)**
>
> This serial Key recovery tool enables you to
>   recover your product CD-keys and serial numbers for Microsoft products
>   as well as several 3rd party products. It is important to note that
>   geProductKeys does not work with Windows 7 or Windows Vista and you
>   may have to disable Data Execution Prevention to use this program in
>   Windows XP SP2 and later.
>
> 16) **[MSKeyViewer Plus](http://www.toddandkeelee.com/files/miscellaneous/MSKeyViewerPlus-v2.0.5.zip)**
>
> Simple utility to view program installation keys,
>   service pack levels, and product IDs along with detecting many other
>   non-licensed program versions. Supports Microsoft Windows, Office,
>   Exchange, SQL Server, Norton AntiVirus 2004-2007, and more.
>
> 17) **[Product Key Informer](http://www.gtdelphicomponents.gr/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/pki.zip)**
>
> It retrieves product key or License Key
>   information pertaining to the operating system. The tool is very
>   useful for Network Administrators for organizing the product key info
>   of their network terminals.
>
> 18) **[ViewKeyXP](http://www.angelfire.com/va3/vic3/ViewKeyXP.zip)**
>
> This is a simple tool that recovers your Windows XP key
>   quickly.
>
> 19) **[Game Key Revealer](http://cakirbey.googlepages.com/gamekeyrevealer)**
>
> If you are looking for a free tool to retrieve
>   the CD-Key and Serial for installed games on computer then Game Key
>   Revealer is the best pickup. If you lost legal CD-Keys or Serials of
>   your purchased games, you can easily recover them using Game Key
>   Revealer. You can easily recover serial keys of around 1000 games with
>   Game Key Revealer. The tool also provides you with an option to Save
>   to Text or Word or Print Product Keys for secure backup
>
> 20) **[SyberCorp’ Windows Product Key Viewer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sybercorp/)**
>
> It is yet another and simple
>   serial key (CD Keys) recovery software. With Windows Product Key
>   Viewer you can view and change your Windows Product Key anytime.
>
> 21) **[Skeleton Key](http://sourceforge.net/projects/logansoftsk/)**
>
> Skeleton Key is an open source and simplest software
>   to find a product key.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, the CD key is not stored directly in any file. For some Microsoft products (e.g., Office, and [apparently Windows 7 too](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html)), the registry contains a licensing blob where the CD key can be extracted. See the link for a program that can extract this information.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully activated (an inactivated version of) Windows XP Pro with a key found by Produkey, so I assume in Windows XP there is a key in the install files. I do not know the legality of this endeavor, though.